# How to be changed this code <div></div data-isloaded="true">

Tags: jquery, html

i'm new in jquery plz help me to change this code

```
 <div></div data-isloaded="true">
```

to this code

```
 <div></div data-isloaded="false">
```

with jquery

Comment: What exactly you are trying to do?
It looks exactly the same?

Comment: i have one photo gallery with some pic in div .and im added filter img to this gallery.i want to delete some photo from photo viewer who data-isloaded='false'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('div[data-isloaded="true"]').attr('data-isloaded',false)
```